# excel index match vlookup - return value based on criteria in two columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, criteria, vlookup

A courier company uses cars with tanks that are filled up with fuel fully each Sunday evening. 
On Sunday night, the empty car is weighed without a driver by 2 scales (each with its own variance).

```
date    car scale   weight  note 
04/29   014 scale_1 1244.3  fillup 
04/29   014 scale_2 1247.1  fillup 
04/29   015 scale_1 1200.9  fillup 
04/29   015 scale_2 1203.7  fillup
```

Throughout a week the packages are loaded early in the morning, and cars are emptied in the evening and weighed.

```
date    car scale   weight  note 
04/30   014 scale_1 1213.3  returned to depot 
04/30   014 scale_2 1216.1  returned to depot 
04/30   015 scale_1 1144.9  returned to depot 
04/30   015 scale_2 1147.7  returned to depot 
05/01   014 scale_1 1167.8  returned to depot 
05/01   014 scale_2 1170.6  returned to depot 
05/01   015 scale_1 1052.9  returned to depot 
05/01   015 scale_2 1055.7  returned to depot
```

per scale 1 the variance is 45.5 kg as well as per scale 2, on 05/01 compared to 04/30

How do I create a function in a column(s), to the right - one(s) after "note", which will give me variance to previous measurement, based on the scale and the car ? 
(lookup last "weight" value from the same "scale" & same "car" and subtract it from current measurement)

Comment: There is only one date in the first data listing: if you had Sunday weights for more than one week, would they be in increasing order of date?

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar to  learnAsWeGo. Try:

```
=E9-(INDEX($E$2:$E8,MATCH(1,MATCH($D$2:$D8,D9,0),-1)))
```

I created another column between scale and weight. This column concats car+scale. In the column where you want to show the difference, enter the formula above. You'll want to throw an iferror in there for instances where it can't locate a match.

[Last occurrence difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yphRk.png)